# ActiveRecord db optimization: group by 2 columns count

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

Currently I have a query that looks like this:

```
Model.group(:column1, :column2).count
```

Where both column1 and column2 are indexed. I've noticed that it gets pretty slow at scale. Would I get a performance gain by adding an index with both columns (ie `add_index :models, [:column1, :column2]`? If not, is there some other way to boost performance here?

Comment: Try looking at the query generated and use ´EXPLAIN´  to see the query plan in Postgres. Or just try adding the index in a migration and roll it back if it does not improve performance.

Comment: You can either use `rails db:console` and run the query manually or `Model.group(:column1, :column2).explain`